# Ansible doesn't seems to apply encrypted vault password but reads the vault file

Tags: ansible, ubuntu-20.04, openbsd, ansible-vault

I'm new to ansible and trying to create new user with encrypted password using ansible-vault. The taget system is OpenBsd, and I'm using ansible 2.10 on Ubuntu 20.04
.
The "problem" is once the playbook finished, I get this message in output

`"passord": "NOT_LOGGING_PASSWORD"` and the password is not set/update.

I first create and edit my vault file using ansble-vault.

Content of my vault file:

`user_pass: pass`

Here is my playbook:

```
- name: Add new user
  hosts: all
  vars_files:
    - "../vars/pass.yml"

  tasks:
  - name: Add regular user
    user:
      name: foo
      update_password: always
      password: "{{ vault_user_pass | password_hash('sha512') }}"
      create_home: yes
      shell: /bin/sh
      generate_ssh_key: yes
      ssh_key_type: rsa
      ssh_key_bits: 2048
      ssh_key_passphrase: ''
    become_user: root
```

Do you have any idea why the password is not set/update ? I tried to print the vault variable to check if var is readable or not, using debug module and yes, it is. The user is created but with another password. I also tried to hash the password using mkpasswd but same results.

If you need further informations, don't hesitate :).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: From https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/faq.html#how-do-i-generate-encrypted-passwords-for-the-user-module => `In OpenBSD, a similar option is available in the base system called encrypt (1)` Did you try ?

Answer (score 0):

The variable name is `user_pass`, even though your variable is in a vault file you don't need to use the vault prefix.

Try as below

```yaml
- name: Add new user
  hosts: all
  vars_files:
    - "../vars/pass.yml"

  tasks:
  - name: Add regular user
    user:
      name: foo
      update_password: always
      password: "{{ user_pass | password_hash('sha512') }}"
      create_home: yes
      shell: /bin/sh
      generate_ssh_key: yes
      ssh_key_type: rsa
      ssh_key_bits: 2048
      ssh_key_passphrase: ''
    become_user: root
```

Comment: My bad, the variable has the same name "vault_user_pass"in both files

Comment: no worry, how are executing your playbook? could you write a debug task with var "vault_user_pass" to see the value?

Comment: The playbook is launched with ```ansible-playbook tasks/add.yml -i inventory.yml --ask-vault-pass  -u root -v ```